# Customize double click for text box

Tags: c#

```
private void newThumbNail(int docType, string fileName)
{
  thmbNail[thmbNailCnt] = new GroupBox();
  thmbNail[thmbNailCnt].Parent = panel1;            
  thmbNail[thmbNailCnt].Visible = true;
  thmbNail[thmbNailCnt].Location = new Point(2, 5 + ((thmbNailCnt * 50) + 2));
  thmbNail[thmbNailCnt].Size = new Size(222, 50);

  picBox[thmbNailCnt] = new PictureBox();
  picBox[thmbNailCnt].Parent = thmbNail[thmbNailCnt];
  picBox[thmbNailCnt].Visible = true;
  picBox[thmbNailCnt].Location = new Point(6, 13);
  picBox[thmbNailCnt].Size = new Size(31, 31);

  switch (docType)
  {
    case 1: picBox[thmbNailCnt].Image = wordImg;
      break;
    case 2: picBox[thmbNailCnt].Image = pptImg;
      break;
    case 3: picBox[thmbNailCnt].Image = excelImg;
      break;
    case 4: picBox[thmbNailCnt].Image = pdfImg;
      break;
  }


  texBox[thmbNailCnt] = new TextBox();
  texBox[thmbNailCnt].Parent = thmbNail[thmbNailCnt];
  texBox[thmbNailCnt].Visible = true;
  texBox[thmbNailCnt].Location = new Point(53, 24);
  texBox[thmbNailCnt].Size = new Size(163, 20);
  texBox[thmbNailCnt].Text = fileName;
  texBox[thmbNailCnt].Enabled = false;
  texBox[thmbNailCnt].BackColor = Color.Silver;
  texBox[thmbNailCnt].ForeColor = Color.Black;
  texBox[thmbNailCnt].DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(changeText);

  thmbNailFN[thmbNailCnt] = fileName;
  data[thmbNailCnt, 0] = fileName;
  data[thmbNailCnt, 1] = docType.ToString(); 

  thmbNail[thmbNailCnt].Controls.Add(picBox[thmbNailCnt]);
  thmbNail[thmbNailCnt].Controls.Add(texBox[thmbNailCnt]);

  thmbNailCnt++;
}

private void changeText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.Enabled = true;
}
```

The private void newThumbNail, adds a group box with picture box and text box as its elements. I have customize a double click event for the text Box, unfortunately it does not executes. Why is that so?

Comment: Is `this.Enabled` ever false?  If the parent container (`this`) is disabled, it won't receive any events.  .Net does not have control arrays, so I'm a bit confused with what I'm seeing with this code sample.

Answer (score 1):

Your event won't fire because the TextBox is disabled. However I think the the solution might be a redesign of your interface since it is not expected behaviour for a control to be enabled when double-clicked. The whole point of disabling a control is to prevent a user from interacting with it.

Perhaps setting it to readonly might be a better option? That way it will still fire events.

Answer (score 1):

The DoubleClick event will not fire on the TextBox if it is not enabled. So, it will not work because you are doing this:

```
texBox[thmbNailCnt].Enabled = false;
```

I presume you meant to do the following in the double click handler (instead of using `this`)

```
(sender as TextBox).Enabled = true;
```

You must be trying to make the textbox enable itself with a double click?

If so, then you can't use the Enabled property because the click events will not fire while your textbox is disabled.

Instead, you can use the `ReadOnly` property which will prevent the user from making any changes to the text:

```
texBox[thmbNailCnt].ReadOnly = true;
```

and

```
private void changeText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as TextBox).ReadOnly = false;
}
```

This will not give it the dimmed out look it has when it is disabled. You could make some aditional changes to get it looking the same though if you wanted.